# Telerik RADControls for WPF : Improving performance

Tags: visual-studio-2008, telerik

Today I started using the WPF controls on a small dev project. One solution with three projects (a function library, a console app for testing, and a WPF app for the main UI deliverable) The form has less than a dozen controls at this time (a couple of textboxes, some buttons, and the form itself). The controls are a mix of Microsoft and Telerik controls. Performance was fine until I started switching out MS buttons for Telerik buttons. Now it takes several seconds for VS to respond after selecting a control. Selecting a line in the XAML view and then jumping back to the designer view (split screen) takes 4-5 seconds. Working with VS like this is truly unacceptable and I find it really hard to believe it's Telerik. If it is, how can anyone work like that?

Do you have any suggestions for troubleshooting this?
Recommendations for improving performance?

edit:

- All development and testing is done locally.
- All software and libraries installed locally.
- There is no network involved.
- Resharper 4.5, CodeSmith 5.2, and dotTrace 3.1 are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Silverlight not long ago and got fed up with the VS designer. So [I stopped using it and set VS to display only the xaml code](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/01/29/life-changer-xaml-tip-for-visual-studio.aspx) and used Blend instead for the designer bit that couldn't be done directly in the xaml.

> 1. Right-click on a XAML file in the Solution Explorer
> 2. Select "Open With..."
> 3. Select "Source Code (Text) Editor"
> 4. Click on "Set as Default"
> 5. Click OK

Hope the WPF designer will be faster in VS 2010

Comment: I've been working with Blend this morning and it's much snappier than VS.